# Hover an Element, Affect another

Tags: html, css

When I hover on top of #empresas is not affecting the height of the #personas div. Why's that?

HTML

```
     <div id="hugeBanners">

        <div id="personas">
            <h3 class="personasText1">Servicios Para ti</h3>
        </div>

        <div id="empresas">
            <h3 class="empresasText1">Servicios Para tu Empresa</h3>
        </div>

      </div>
```

CSS

```
#personas {
width: 100%;
height: 40%;
position: absolute;
top:20%;
background-color: green;
cursor: pointer;
transition: height 0.2s ease;
}

#personas:hover {
height: 70%;
}

#personas:hover ~ #empresas {
height: 10%;
}

#empresas {
width: 100%;
height: 40%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
background-color: aqua;
cursor:pointer;
transition: height 0.2s ease;
}

#empresas:hover {
height: 70%;
}

#empresas:hover ~ #personas {
height: 10%;
}
```

What's happening because when you hover on top of #personas it works perfectly, resizing the height of #empresas.

Comment: Because of relative heights may be? But **works fine for me: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MELQEB**

Comment: there is no previous sibling selector - unfortunately ~ means any following siblings

Comment: There is no way to affect a preceding element sibling with pure CSS, you can only affect adjacent (+) or general(~) **following** siblings. You would need a JavaScript solution if you want the second div to affect the first on hover.

Comment: thanks @Soolie But see if you hover on top of the bottom one it doesn't affect the top one.

Comment: @delinear I've tried first with javascript and it was working fine but someone I couldn't make it animate smoothly that's why I was trying with css

Comment: @Eugenio It works in the codepen... Kindly check. The top one gets reduced. I am using Chrome...

Comment: @Eugenio you can still use CSS for the animation, just use JavaScript to add/remove a CSS class.

Comment: https://codepen.io/svitch/pen/QqYQox

Comment: SOLVED!! with this

$(function() {
   $('#personas').hover(function() {
   $('#personas').css('height', '70%');
   $('#empresas').css('height', '10%');
   }, function() {
   // on mouseout, reset the background colour
   $('#personas').css('height', '40%');
   $('#empresas').css('height', '40%');
   });
  });